# Mkdocs hyperlink not working in static pages

Tags: mkdocs

I'm trying to build a documentation with mkdocs. 
The problem is that the links in the static created pages are not working. 
Instead of going to [folder]/index.html I'm presented with the following page like in the following [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQ5y9.png)

The problem however doesn't exist when i try mkdocs serve

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Set the [use_directory_urls](http://www.mkdocs.org/user-guide/configuration/#use_directory_urls) setting to `false` in your `mkdocs.yml` config file:

```
use_directory_urls: false
```

The documentation explains:

> This setting controls the style used for linking to pages within the
>   documentation.
>
> The following table demonstrates how the URLs used on the site differ
>   when setting `use_directory_urls` to `true` or `false`.
>
> ```
> Source file  | Generated HTML       | use_directory_urls: true | use_directory_urls: false
> ------------ | -------------------- | ------------------------ | ------------------------
> index.md     | index.html           | /                        | /index.html
> api-guide.md | api-guide/index.html | /api-guide/              | /api-guide/index.html
> about.md     | about/index.html     | /about/                  | /about/index.html
> ```
>
> The default style of `use_directory_urls: true` creates more user
>   friendly URLs, and is usually what you'll want to use.
>
> The alternate style can occasionally be useful if you want your
>   documentation to remain properly linked when opening pages directly
>   from the file system, because it create links that point directly to
>   the target *file* rather than the target
>   *directory*.

The last paragraph is the key to why this makes a difference.